# Why can't I register a dropzone.js callback in my "ready" function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have spent a few days working with dropzone.js for the first time.

I have made the following configuration to make a translation to Swedish and create a callback (dropzoneFinished) when a drop is :

```
$(function () {
    if (currentCulture == "sv-SE") {
        Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            dictDefaultMessage: "Släpp dokument här som ska laddas upp.",
            dictFallbackMessage: "Din webbläsare har inte stöd för att ladda upp dokument genom att dra och släppa.",
            dictFallbackText: "Använd följande formulär för att ladda upp dokument på gammalt sätt.",
            dictFileTooBig: "Dokumentet är för stor ({{filesize}}MiB). Maximal dokumentstorlek: {{maxFilesize}}MiB.",
            dictInvalidFileType: "Du kan inte ladda upp dokument av denna typ.",
            dictResponseError: "Servern svarar med felkod {{statusCode}}.",
            dictCancelUpload: "Avbryt dokumentuppladdningen",
            dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "Är du säker på att du vill avbryta denna dokumentuppladdning?",
            dictRemoveFile: "Ta bort dokument",
            dictMaxFilesExceeded: "Du kan inte ladda upp fler dokument.",
            init: function () {
                this.on("complete", function(file) {
                    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                        dropzoneFinished();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    } else {
        Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            /* Added period. */
            dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload.",
            init: function () {
                this.on("complete", function (file) {
                    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                        dropzoneFinished();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    };
});
```

However I would like to separate the general culture configuration from the more specific callback logic. So I tried to move the registration of the callback to my ready function:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropzoneForm').on('complete', function (file) {
            if ($('#dropzoneForm').getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && $('#dropzoneForm').getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
                dropzoneFinished();
            }
        });
    });
```

But then on complete will not be called.
Anybody knows why?
Are there any other ways to split up different types of Dropzone.options?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I needed to use "complete" logic. However, according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp, there is no event named as "complete" or "oncomplete". And the reason for that may be that this event is about response from somewhere. For instance, what do you mean for some element to "complete"? In form case, there may be submission of it, but for this "onsubmit" event exists. However, the form is just submitted, nothing is told about "complete" condition. Thus, on element #dropzoneForm (which may be a form or anything on you page with #dropzoneForm id) you can not attach "complete" event, since it is not defined.

But your Dropzone has complete event, because events can be defined. So, instead of writing:

```
$('#dropzoneForm').on('complete', function (file) {
    if ($('#dropzoneForm').getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && $('#dropzoneForm').getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        dropzoneFinished();
    }
});
```

You may write:

```
Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm.init = function () {
    this.on("complete", function () {
        if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
            dropzoneFinished();
        }
    });
}
```

In this way you will get the same functionality as previously. And this would solve your problem.

Finally, with this solution may be another issue. What if you want to initialize dropzoneForm with more functionality than this? In this case you should move this code to dropzone.js, and put it after if-else statement. This would work, too.